# Ace editor Processing mode?

Tags: processing, ace-editor

I uploaded a processing file to github. I want to show the code on my website. So I implement [ACE](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=about) editor in my site and ajaxed my proecessing code to the ace editor. But there is a problem.

I want the code showed on my look as the code show in Processing IDE. But Ace editor support java language but no mode for processing. How can I solve this problem ? I could not find any package for Ace processing mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://hello.processing.org/editor/ uses Ace, and it have a mode for processing see http://hello.processing.org/js/vendor/ace/mode-processing.js

Comment: You are so smart by discover this way !!  I tried it. But the code:
`var ProcessingHighlightRules = require("./processing_highlight_rules").ProcessingHighlightRules;`
seem it requires more file, but I could not find that. Do you want to try the whole thing out ?

Comment: it doesn't require more files there is `define('ace/mode/processing_highlight_rules'` in that same file.

Comment: okay!!  I've achieve this! Maybe the version of ACE has changed. So remember to change `define` method to `ace.define`. And the way @a_user provided is good and usable. Thanks a lot :))

Comment: And by the way, The `mode` and `theme` from the website is not as good as I expect. Even, It looks bad. If there is more theme or mode, please tell :))